# Poltergeist ReferenceError: Can't find variable: RWR

Tags: react-redux

I have recently installed rwr-redux in my project and the Rails feature specs now fail with the following error:

```
Capybara::Poltergeist::JavascriptError:
  One or more errors were raised in the Javascript code on the page. If you don't care about these errors, you can ignore them by setting js_errors: false in your Poltergeist configuration (see documentation for details).

  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: RWR
  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: RWR
      at http://127.0.0.1:65150/assets/application-a3b817ad22570913fde9f581c275f3c7cca4f7e364708af51a5226a506b3ef53.js:14564 in _mountNodes
      at :0 in dispatchEvent
      at http://127.0.0.1:65150/assets/application-a3b817ad22570913fde9f581c275f3c7cca4f7e364708af51a5226a506b3ef53.js:12191 in dispatch
      at http://127.0.0.1:65150/assets/application-a3b817ad22570913fde9f581c275f3c7cca4f7e364708af51a5226a506b3ef53.js:12191 in notifyApplicationAfterPageLoad
      at http://127.0.0.1:65150/assets/application-a3b817ad22570913fde9f581c275f3c7cca4f7e364708af51a5226a506b3ef53.js:12191 in pageLoaded
      at http://127.0.0.1:65150/assets/application-a3b817ad22570913fde9f581c275f3c7cca4f7e364708af51a5226a506b3ef53.js:12191
```

The pages definitely load without Javascript errors. I don't want to set `js_errors: false` because the react components then do not render.

From my index.jsx file where RWR is being run:

```
import 'babel-polyfill';

import RWR, { integrationsManager } from 'react-webpack-rails'; 
import RWRRedux from 'rwr-redux';

RWR.run(); 
integrationsManager.register('redux-store',   RWRRedux.storeIntegrationWrapper); 
integrationsManager.register('redux-container', RWRRedux.containerIntegrationWrapper);
```

I have tried clobbering assets and precompiling prior to running rspec to ensure react_bundle is being generated but I get the same error. Any idea what is going on here?